# Applying ST_Intersection on a list of geometries

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm new to postgis, so, sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have a list of polygons in a table and I want to find the intersetion between all of them.
I can do a ST_Union without problems like so:

`select ST_Union(t.geom) from mytable t`

but the same doesn't work with ST_Intersection

`` select ST_Intersection(t.geom) from mytable t`
ERROR:  function st_intersection(geometry) does not exist ``

Looking at the documentation for [ST_Union](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html) vs. [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersection.htmll), they really have different signatures, which suggests that unlinke ST_Union, ST_Intersection can only be applied to exactly 2 geometries.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to find the geometry that is the intersection of all of them? Do they all overlap a common region?

Comment: ?1 Exactly. ?2 Yes, in most cases. If not, then the intersection will have a 0-area and that information is important too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`WITH RECURSIVE` common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) to process each element of a `geometry[]` with a running result.

Here is some example data, based on overlapped buffered random locations (blue polygons in the figure):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ar;
SELECT array_agg(ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(random(), random()), 0.5, 3)) AS geoms
INTO TEMP ar
FROM generate_series(1, 6) AS id;
SELECT ST_Collect(geoms) FROM ar;
```

And here is the magic:

```
WITH RECURSIVE inter AS (
   -- First geometry
   SELECT 1 AS idx, geoms[1] AS geom FROM ar a
   UNION ALL
   -- Remaining geometries with the previous result
   SELECT a.idx + 1, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geoms[a.idx + 1])
   FROM inter a, ar b
   WHERE a.idx + 1 <= array_length(geoms, 1) AND NOT ST_IsEmpty(a.geom)
)
SELECT * FROM inter
ORDER BY idx DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The "recursion" stops on either the last array index, or if the result is empty. Also, you can see each intersection step by commenting out the last line.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

You need a [self join](http://www1.udel.edu/evelyn/SQL-Class3/SQL3_self.html).
In example:

```
SELECT ST_intersection(a.geom,b.geom) 
FROM mytable AS a, mytable AS b 
WHERE st_equals(a.geom, b.geom) IS FALSE AND ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

In this way can you compare a table to itself. The two where conditions guarantee that:

- the two geometries are not the same
- the two geometries intersect (otherwise ST_Intersections would return `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY`)

If your table have a ID column, you could use

```
WHERE a.id != b.id
```

instead of

```
WHERE st_equals(a.geom, b.geom) IS FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! This is not exactly what I needed by this idea may come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/query-to-find-the-intersection-coordinates-of-multiple-polyon/60295#60295) which seems worked best for my case.

After creating the function `ST_IntersectionArray` like suggested

`create or replace function ST_IntersectionArray(geoms geometry[]) returns geometry as $$
declare
   i integer;
   tmpGeom geometry;
begin
    tmpGeom := geoms[1];
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(geoms,1) LOOP
      tmpGeom:= ST_Intersection(tmpGeom,geoms[i]);
    END LOOP;
    return tmpGeom;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

You can do

`select ST_Intersection(array_agg(distinct t.geom)) from mytable t`

The distinct is important. If there are identical polygons if might give an error.

This is what worked best for me.